# The meaning of どちらが割に合うんだかな

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> 「そんな顔をするな。これで何かあったら、さすがに寝覚めが悪いだろう？　それにワシはお前が嬢ちゃんくらいのひよっこの頃から面倒見てるんだからな。恩人の頼みは聞くもんだ」
>
> 「連れ戻してきたら、ご馳走するぞ。今朝いい肉が入ってな」
>
> 「ったく、銀貨５枚と**どちらが割に合うんだかな**」
>
> 他の探索者は面倒ごとに関わるまいと散会している。断れる雰囲気ではなさそうだ。

My question is about the meaning of 「ったく、銀貨５枚と**どちらが割に合うんだかな**」.

Context: A young boy came to the adventurers guild with a request but only had several silver coins(edit: if you read on much further you find out it was 5 silver coins). The guild master told the boy that he wouldn't send his members for such a small reward.

Before the young boy leaves an aspiring members of the guild accepts his request. The guild master (worried about the potential impact on the guild if the member dies, or is found out as this member has not yet received their license). He then tells someone else to go and save her, and the above conversation begins.

割に合う from what I understand (in this context) means "to be worth it". However, I don't quite follow what is meant in the excerpt above. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your words. I think it is something like "I wonder what is/would be more worth it, those 5 silver coins that boy offered, or this 'free' meal I will receive. Clearly dissatisfied with the the reward he will receive, which is presumably, worth less and the request will be more troublesome if he has to look after this other person as well.

Comment: どちら from my understanding is used when there are two sides to things. In this case one is the 5 silver coins and the other is?

Comment: "5 silver coins" versus "free meal". The guy is giving a sarcastic comment here. Basically, the nuance is "(Of course the five coins is not really worth my effort, but) is the free meal any better (than the five coins)?"

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your quote,「ったく、銀貨５枚とどちらが割に合うんだかな」, "ったく" doesn't make sense in Japanese. Is it "全く"？ Something is missing.

"どちらが割に合うんだかな" means "Which would be worth more?" or "Which is more advantageous (profitable)?"

A more common way of saying this is "どちらが割に合うのかな" or "どちらが割に合うの（ん）だか." I think "な" at the tail is used for the purpose of emphasis or self-affirmation. It's a colloquial turn of phrase, but it's very, very rare to hear such an expression - 割に合うんだかな.

Comment: "ったく" (from まったく) is a phrase commonly found today in manga and light novels. I don't think this んだかな is unnatural, either...at least in fiction.